# Geometric Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, poisson-process, levy-processes

- $\lambda >0$
- $ \sigma > 1$
- $n_t$ si a Poisson process
- $S_t = S_0 \exp( N_t \log( \sigma +1) - \lambda \sigma t ) = S_t e^{- \lambda \sigma t } ( \sigma +1 )^{N_t} $
- $ M_t= N_t - \lambda t$ is the compensated Poisson measure

We want to prove [the result slide 14](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/%7Eapopier/enseignement/ENSTA/slides_calcul_sto_JDP.pdf) :

$$S_t= S(0) + \int_0^t S(u_{-} ) dM_u$$

---

- $X_t=N_t \log( \sigma +1) - \lambda \sigma t$
- $f(x)=S_0 e^x$
- We apply Ito formula with jumps.

\begin{align*}
f(X_t)&= f(X_0)+ \int_{0}^t f'(X_u) dX^{c}  + \sum_{0<u \leq t} [ f(X_u) - f({X_u}^-) ] \\
f(X_t)&= S_0 - \int_{0}^t \lambda s S_s ds +  \sum_{0<u \leq t} [ f(X_u) - {X_u}^- ] \\ 
f(X_u) - f({X_u}^-)&= S_{u^{-}} \left( e^{ \ln (\sigma +1)}-1 \right) \mathbb{1}_{ \Delta N_u \ne 0} \\
\sum_{0<u \leq t} [ f(X_u) - {X_u}^- ] &= \int_0^t S_{u-} dN_u \\
\int_{0}^t \lambda s S_s ds &= \int_{0}^t \lambda u S_{u ^{-} } ds \\
S_t&= S_0 + \int_0^t S_{u-} dM_u \\
\end{align*}

With respect to Lebesgue measure $\int S_{ u^{-} }du = \int S_u du $

references :

- [stochastic integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38068/how-to-evaluate-the-following-stochastic-integral)
- [quadratic variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143200/how-to-compute-the-quadratic-variation-of-a-compound-poisson-process)

Comment: The Ito formula with jumps is on their slide 13. What exactly is the trouble you are having?

Comment: It should be fine now. Thanks.